# Android Room Database How to Filter By String Value in Room

Tags: android, database

```
@Dao
public interface DaoAccess {

    @Insert
    void insertImage(ImagesOfEmployee image);

    @Query("Select * from ImagesOfEmployee where id like '%' || :id ||'%'")
    String getProfileImagePathByID(String id);

    @Query(("Delete from ImagesOfEmployee where id like '%' || :id || '%'"))
    void deleteEmployee(String id);
}

@Entity
public class ImagesOfEmployee {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    String id;
    @ColumnInfo
    String path;

    public ImagesOfEmployee(String id, String path) {
        this.id = id;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

**I don't know how to filter In Room Database Android String Query
Can Any One Know How to do this**

I AM attaching the error below. what android studio shows me in the error box
Screen Shot
[This is ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TageP.png)

Comment: It will be ImagesOfEmployee object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android studio error says 'not sure how to convert cursor to the method's return type' as the query with `'Select *'` will return the whole record, and I think you are trying to get only path of the image, Just replace * with path as in,

```
Select path from ImagesOfEmployee where id like '%' || :id ||'%'
```

hope you are looking for this only.

Comment: thanks man. You solved my Problem And i learn something more about room from you

Comment: glad to hear it was useful. if it solved your problem then can you kindly upvote my answer?

Comment: website cant let me upvote your answer needs 15 reputation

Comment: no issues, once you click upvote button,  the website will record it and once you reach to 15 rep. the upvote will get released. ignore if already clicked.  :)